# Exporting to Excel with Condition

Tags: regex, excel, python-2.7

i am trying to Export the data to excel .

```
list = [{'ip': u'9.11.180.3','endpoint': u'rd2ff5-az2-1519-1520_eth1-18_vpc', 'hostname': u'RD2APIC1', 'encap': u'vlan-42', 'epg': u'19_14_140_172', 'extpaths': u'topology/pod-2/protpaths-1519-1520/pathep-[rd2ff5-az2-1519-1520_eth1-18_vpc]'},{'ip': u'14.10.5.5','endpoint': u'eth1/2','hostname': u'RD2APIC1', 'encap': u'vlan-18', 'epg': u'14_70_7_0', 'extpaths': u'topology/pod-2/paths-1511/extpaths-102/pathep-[eth1/2]'}]
```

**My Code :**

```
filename = self.controller + ".xls"
        excel_file = xlwt.Workbook()
        sheet = excel_file.add_sheet('HOSTLIST')
        sheet.write(0, 0, "APIC")            
        sheet.write(0, 1, "VLAN")
        sheet.write(0, 2, "EPG")
        sheet.write(0, 3, "EndPoint")
        sheet.write(0, 4, "Extpath")
        for count in xrange(1, len(list) + 1):
            if list[count - 1]["epg"]:
                epg = list[count - 1]["epg"]
            else:
                epg = "UNKNOWN"                
            sheet.write(count, 0, list[count - 1].get("hostname","UNKNOWN"))
            sheet.write(count, 1, list[count - 1].get("encap","UNKNOWN"))
            sheet.write(count, 2, epg)
            sheet.write(count, 3, list[count - 1].get("endpoint","UNKNOWN"))
            sheet.write(count, 4, list[count - 1].get("extpaths","UNKNOWN"))
        excel_file.save(filename)
```

Basically i need to split the "endpoint" .Need to remove the section after "_ "

in this case "endpoint - `rd2ff5-az2-1519-1520_eth1-18_vpc`" needs to be split as `rd2ff5-az2-1519-1520`and export to excel .

Any suggestion / idea ?

Comment: Should "needs to be splited as `rd2ff5-az2-1519` and `rd2ff5-az2-1519`" be worded as "needs to be split as `rd2ff5-az2-1519` and `rd2ff5-az2-1520` and two rows inserted instead of one"?

Comment: @DeanTaylor yep ,edited as per your suggestion

Comment: It still says "rd2ff5-az2-1519" twice.

Comment: You should also edit your question to also include example(s) of what you have tried.